# PostgreSQL trigger to make default value refer to another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, default-value

PostgreSQL default values cannot contain variables or refer to any other columns in the table, or in a different table.

However, is it possible to use a trigger to create a "Default value" that will behave in the following manner. First, let me illustrate with two example tables:

```
create table projects
(
id serial primary key,
created_at timestamp with time zone default now()
);

create table last_updated
(
project_id integer primary key references projects,
updated_at timestamp with time zone default ...
);
```

In the second table (`last_updated`) I would like the default to be something like `default projects(created_at)`. I.e. if a date is not specified for `updated_at`, look at the project_id referenced in the projects table, find the created_at date, and set the updated_at to this date. However, you cannot write this as per the first paragraph of my question.

So how do you write a trigger that will give this functionality?

Comment: Presumably, you'd create an insert trigger to check whether `NEW.updated_at IS NULL` and select the appropriate value from `projects` into `NEW.updated_at` if it is, in fact, NULL.

Comment: Do note that the sole purpose of such a trigger would be to maintain redundancy. Referring from last_updated.project_id -> projects. created_at would yield the same value; even at a later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer depends on what you do not specify. Typically, one would make updates to the `projects` table and then audit that in the `last_updated` table, using an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on table `projects`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION audit_project_update () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO last_updated VALUES
    (NEW.id,   -- NEW refers to the updated record in the projects table
     now()     -- this would be the logical value, but can use NEW.created_at
     -- other columns, possibly log session_user
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_projects_update
  AFTER UPDATE ON projects
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_project_update();
```

Note that in this approach there is never a situation where an `INSERT` is made on table `last_updated` without specifying a value for `updated_at`, assuming that you will not `GRANT INSERT` to any role on table `last_updated`, because the trigger function always specifies `now()`. In the table definition you do not have to specify a default value anymore: the trigger gives you the automated behavior you are looking for.

Your stated question - and confirmed in the comment below - would also use a trigger, but then on the `last_updated` table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION project_last_updated () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.updated_at IS NULL) THEN
    SELECT created_at INTO NEW.updated_at
    FROM projects
    WHERE id = NEW.project_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_projects_update
  BEFORE INSERT ON last_updated
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE project_last_updated();
```

This specification begs the question why you do not simply add a column `updated_at` to the `projects` table. Since the `project_id` column is PK in the `last_update` table, you can only store a single last update date per project.

Comment: Thanks, this would create an entry in `last_updated` every time an entry is added to `projects`, correct? What I would actually like is to be able to manually create an entry in `last_updated` with a reference to an existing `projects.id`, and if the `last_updated.updated_at` field is not specified, to find the `created_at` date from the projects table and use it as the default.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I want. To answer your question " begs the question why you do not simply add a column updated_at to the projects table.", the pair of tables is the  bare minimum example I could give. The `last_updated` at table, for example, could be used to generate reports for selected `project_ids`.